# Link to the main site

Tags: support, feature-request, status-declined

OK Maybe I am really dumb and fail to see something obvious, but I am not able to find a link to the main site (i.e. codegolf.stackexchange.com) in the non-mobile view of this meta site. I can find the link at the bottom of the page in the mobile view, or find the link to the right of the edit box when I start to ask a question.

Can anyone please tell me where the link to codegolf.stackexchange.com is located on the non-mobile view of the homepage of codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com, or help to add it if there really isn't one?

Edit (the edit was made before the question had an answer, and is the same as the comment by @ASCII-only. The latter is now included in @Mr.XCoder's answer with a illustrative picture): I can click the final button on the toolbar at the upper-right corner to get a link to the main site but is there a more obvious place that holds the link to the main site?

Comment: Just type out the link? Is it too long to type? On [se] there is magic link shortcut `[codegolf.se]`.

Comment: @user202729 The point is that such a link exists on many meta sites in the SE network and I don't see the reason why it shouldn't be here as well. (Of course there are many without this link too.)

Comment: Many? I can't find a link on [math.meta.se] to [math.se].

Comment: @user202729 I guess that I would raise a question on meta.stackexchange.com but I first want to make sure I am not missing something obvious. I will leave this question open as a signpost.

Comment: @user202729 I confirm that such a link exist in the right of the page on a SE site that you don't already have an account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by ASCII-only, it is available when you open the hamburger menu resembling SE's favicon:

[image: From the hamburger menu]

You can also access it via your profile (or anyone else's, actually) – this will link you to that person's profile on the main site:

[image: From a user profile]

Of course, if you want to go from meta straight to the main site, just delete the `.meta` from `https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com` :-).

Comment: It's also available under the three-layer hamburger menu on the right of the sidebar.

Comment: Thank you for confirming. Still I think it would be nice to have a direct link like that in the mobile view.

Answer (score 0):

> Still I think it would be nice to have a direct link like that in the mobile view

There is! Just click on the hamburger menu on the top left of your screen, and go here:[image]

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo. I mean a more obvious link in the non-mobile view, but you can keep this answer to help future comers. Actually the link can be found at the bottom of the mobile view, as I mentioned in the question. So if you wish you can include a screenshot of that too.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. I might leave this up just in case it helps someone who can't find it in the future though

Comment: See my updated comment above.